# Can Intersection Observer be used to check if an element has crossed the middle of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

I understand how to use Intersection Observer to check if an element has entered the viewport, such as the code below:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#el')
const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
    console.log('ENTER')
    return
  }
  console.log('LEAVE')
}, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0.1, // set offset 0.1 means trigger if atleast 10% of element in viewport
})

observer.observe(el);
```

Is it possible  to detect if the element crossed the middle of the viewport(`'50vh'` from the top)?

If so, could you please include a code example for clarity?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin

Comment: rootMargin only allows values with % and px. Does the % then correspond to the viewport and not the element or parent?

Comment: "If no root value was passed to the constructor or its value is null, the top-level document's viewport is used." So in this case the parent is the viewport.